# View pushed off screen if app starts with in-call status bar

Tags: ios, objective-c

So when the in-call status bar is toggled when my app is running, everything repositions itself fine. However, when I start the app with the in-call status bar, the entire view gets pushed 20 pixels off screen.

I've done some investigating, and it turns out the navigation controller we're using in the app is what's getting pushed down 20 pixels unnecessarily, causing the view at the very bottom to go off screen.

When I launch the in call status bar while the app is already running, I get a frame that matches the main view, but if I launch the app while the in call status bar is already up, my navigation controller's view sits 20 pixels below the expanded status bar.

Does anyone know why this may be happening? I know I can just re-set the frame when the view loads, but it would be better to fix the root cause of why this is happening.

I appreciate any help!

Comment: You need to update your question with details about how your view hierarchy is created.

Comment: After finding the solution, you're absolutely right. I added the navigation controller as a subview of my main view, but never set the frame of the navigation controller. That caused the issue somehow, still not sure how, but by setting the frame to match my top ViewController's view it sorted everything out.